# Display username after the user logs in using RESTFUL authentication?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, restful-authentication

i'm using RESTFUL authentication on a rails application. The signup/login is working fine. I'm trying to display the username (based on what they logged in with) on the 'members' page they are re-directed to. for example, "Welcome back John!"

any ideas?

thanx

Comment: Put `Welcome back <% @user.name %>!` in your view? You might want to add some info about your problem, why it is not working?

Comment: thanx but i tried that. i get an error page with "undefined method `name' for nil:NilClass".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

thanx Veger, JRL, John and Eric. this fixed the problem.

in the controller
flash[:message] = "welcome back ", current_user.login

and in the view

Answer (score 3):

Use the current_user method provided by RESTful Authentication.

```
Welcome back <%= current_user.name %>
```

Comment: thanx. i tried this...

@welcome_message = current_user (in the controller)

and then <%= @welcome_message %> (in the view)

but it doesn't display the welcome message. any thoughts? thanx

Comment: i tried addind Welcome back <%= current_user.name %>
but i get
undefined local variable or method `current_user.name' for #<ActionView::Base:0x1042794f8>

Comment: Replace `.name` with whatever attribute you're using to hold the user's name.

Answer (score 2):

Put something like the following in your controller (assuming the session variable is `:user_id`):

```
@username = User.find(session[:user_id]).name
```

And then in your view use that variable:

```
Welcome back <%= @username %>
```

Comment: thanx. i tried that. i get 
undefined method `name' for #<User:0x104212028>
how do i know what the session variable is? thanx

Comment: @pixelcode: your message means you found a user, but that the User model does not have a method called name. You need to either provide a method called name, or use the existing column name (if it's 'login', use login).